# What is the difference between the different ways to navigate to a new UIViewController?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard, xib

I seen 3 different implementations of how to init a UIViewController from a xib file. The method I have been using is to create a UIViewController and let Xcode create the xib file as well and then do:

```
let vc = CustomViewController()
navigationController?.push(vc, true)
```

This works and auto-layout works and everything is great.

Why are all the other examples I see online to use:

```
let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CustomViewController") as CustomViewController
```

or:

```
let vc = HomeViewController(nibName: "HomeViewController", bundle: nil)
```

Am I missing something with the way I have been doing things? Please note I don't use segues and storyboard navigation. I separate all my view controllers in their own xib files.

Edit:
I am using the IB to layout my UI and link IBActions back to my source file. That is why I am confused why it works and why I never see this example posted anywhere. Is Xcode doing something behind the scenes to make it work?

Comment: @slickdaddy I am using the IB for my view controllers. I use the IB for all the UI elements and AutoLayout. Also linking IBActions.

Comment: @slickdaddy Exactly, that is why I am surprised that the implementation I been doing for the past years has been working. And I haven't seen anyone else do it. That is also why I am concerned if there is something wrong with the way I am creating view controllers.

Comment: There are multiple ways to instantiate view controllers as you have discovered.  I think part of it is historical and relates to being backwards compatible as over time new technologies and techniques have been available.  For example in the early days, storyboards were not available at all.  If I was you I would try to adopt newer patterns that have been set by Apple as those are recognized by the largest number of developers.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the reason why this works is stated in the Apple Developer Docs. Since I am just calling the default init of the view controller and not overriding `loadView()` it looks through the xib files for the ones matching the view controller's name as explain in  below:

> If you use a nib file to store your view controller's view, it is recommended that you specify that nib file explicitly when initializing your view controller. However, if you do not specify a nib name, and do not override the loadView method in your custom subclass, the view controller searches for a nib file using other means. Specifically, it looks for a nib file with an appropriate name (without the .nib extension) and loads that nib file whenever its view is requested. Specifically, it looks (in order) for a nib file with one of the following names:
>
> It looks for a nib file whose name matches the name of the view controller class. For example, if the class name is MyViewController, it looks for a MyViewController.nib file.

SourceL:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621487-nibname?language=objc